# jQuery, Count num of rows in Datatable (Including All Pages) with specific column value inside a <span> tag. Where Datatable has an AJAX source

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I want to do a client side validation before user request gets submitted. The page has a Datatable `("#datatableOne")` containing column 'Status' (at #7) whose possible values are `'Unknown', 'Completed', 'Pending'`. Also these column value are wrapped inside a `'<span>'` tag.

```
<td>
   <span class="label label-Default">Unknown</span>
</td>
```

One More thing, This table is being loaded using Ajax.

Now I want to calculate the number of rows with **Unknown** status. I tried the following, but it only calculates the count of 'Unknown' rows currently shown and not consider the rest of datatable rows hidden behind other pages.I'm doing it outside (document).ready(),

```
function tableOneRowCount(){
   var rows = $("#datatableOne td:nth-child():contains('Unknown')" ).length;
   alert("Unknown rows :" + rows);
}
```

Also tried doing the following. But this has even more unusual behavior. It is not including the paginated rows unless you make them visible once. so unless I select 2nd page it won't include 'Unknown' rows for 2nd page. Again doing the following outside (document).ready(), in a separate function

```
function tableOneRowCount(){
    var table = $('#datatableOne').DataTable();
    var rows= table.rows(':contains("Unknown")').data().length;
    alert("unknown rows : " + rows);
}
```

Any other approach that I should consider?

Thanks.

Comment: Iterate through all the data... not rows

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this, get all data and then count how meany rows contains Unknown:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  var dataCount = table.rows(':contains("Unknown")').data().length;

  $('#output').text('Number of rows that contain Unknown: ' + dataCount)
  console.log(dataCount);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>Unknown</span>
      </td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div id="output" style="color:red">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this only show the 'Unknown' rows count from the rows currently visible, rest of the paginated rows aren't included.

Comment: No, it will count all the rows. Check the updated code with 16 rows and only showing 10 at a time

Comment: That's strange. Well, I Checked again and it's not including the paginated rows unless you make them visible once. so unless I select 2nd page it won't include 'Unknown' rows for 2nd page.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, because if you look at my snippet the pagination is only showing 10 rows at a time, but the script counts all 16 rows.

You are making an instance of a DataTable() and the counting all the data from it. You are not counting the DOM:elements that are showing.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing differently is trying to calculate the count outside the `(document).ready(function ())` in a separate function which is being called by the onClick event of submit button.
`fucntion ValidateAndConclude() {  // In Here }`
does that make a difference? 
if I do it inside the ready() function, it does't work and shows 0 count.

Comment: I'm loading datatable via ajax, Maybe that's what causing the problem. I tried with static datatable, Its working fine but not when i'm loading datatable via Ajax.